# Twilio script runs locally but not on server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, twilio

I've been using twilio's library just fine locally (mac os x with XAMPP), but when I upload it to an amazon ec2 instance, the ability to send sms messages breaks.

```
$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
          "xxx-xxx-xxxx", $users[pnumber], "Testing!");
```

(the x's are numbers)

The above code seems to be what breaks it. I have uploaded the twilio library to the correct directory. I have also tried enabling all permissions to see if it was a permission issue.

I'm rather inexperienced to running things on my own server. Any guidance, guesses, and tips would be appreciated!

edit: Clarification -  by "breaks", I mean the rest of the page does not load. If I add "echo "Hi";", it will not be printed. However, echo-ing before the code above works.

Comment: When you say breaks, can you describe what went wrong? Did you get an error message? Is it only sending text messages that doesn't work?

Comment: clarified, thanks. The page doesn't load after the code above is reached. No error message, no text sent.

Comment: A few things you can try: 1) ssh into the box and try running the script from the command line, 2) try GETting resources like this, to see if it's just SMS - `foreach($client->account->calls as $call) {
    print $call->price . '\n';
    print $call->duration . '\n';
}`, 3) turn on debug mode for PHP, or try to find out where errors are being logged on your EC2 instance.

Comment: Or maybe you need a dollar sign in front of pnumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had not installed cURL onto my server yet. It was not included in my php installation. Thanks to Kevin Burke's advice, I ran it in command line and realized that it was calling a non-existant function. Some googling led to me installing curl, which fixed the problem. Thanks Kevin!